# how the mysql realize the multiple column index(union index)? what's the datastructure of the multiple column index

Tags: mysql, indexing

yeah，we know that the mysql use the B+ tree to realize the index。 And, you can create union index(multiple column index) on the table.

I want to know how the MySql realize the multiple index, what the structure of the data?

Answer (score 0):

A B+ tree with all the column values concatenated into the keys in the appropriate order.

Comment: what the order is the appropriate order?